# Generalisation of the Beal conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory

If A and B are coprime integers, it seems that at least one of the exponents of the prime factors of AB(A+B) must be one or two.

http://www.comparativetables.com/laeb.htm

Is this interesting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This generalization is false and it fails infinitely often.

Some counterexamples:
$$ 271^3 + 2^3  3^5  73^3=919^3$$
$$ 3^4  29^3  89^3 + 7^3  11^3  167^3=2^7  5^4  353^3$$

In general consider the elliptic curve: $x^3 + y^3 = k$ where
k is 3-full integer, i.e. every exponent is at least 3.

It may have infinitely many rational points $(x'/d,y'/d)$.
Whenever $x',y'$ are coprime it is a counterexample $x'^3+y'^3= k d^3$
and there is explicit construction **added** [ON A CONJECTURE OF ERDOS ON 3-POWERFUL
NUMBERS, ABDERRAHMANE NITAJ](http://www.math.unicaen.fr/~nitaj/erdos.ps).

Comment: To make this more explicit for the OP, take e.g. $A=271^3$ and $B=2^33^573^3$. Then $AB(A+B)=271^32^33^573^3(919^3)$, and no exponent below 3 appears.